# const not recognized and not displayed on console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started with React. why on console a and b are not recognized as 2 and 5?
I know it depends on some React property but I would like to understand the why.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './components/list';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var a = 2;
    var b = 5;  

    const ggg = () => { return a * b };

    console.log(ggg);
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="giol">frff</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: "why on console a and b are not recognized as 2 and 5?" What happens if you do `console.log(a, b)`? What do you expect `console.log(ggg);` to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const ggg = () => { return a * b };` creates a new function. You need to call it in order to log the result.

```js
var a = 2;
var b = 5;  

const ggg = () => { return a * b };

console.log(ggg);
console.log(ggg());
```